# Spliting string in word boundaries requires '+'

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I would like to split a string in word boundaries and hence for now I am considering that whitespace, a ',' and a '.' or '!' signify the boundaries of words.
In the following example:

```
String text = "This is, just a text to be used, for testing purpose. Nothing more!";
String[] words = text.split("[\\s+,.!]");
for(String w: words) {
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

This prints:

```
This
is

just
a
text
to
be
used

for
testing
purpose

Nothing
more
```

As you can see there are empty words for the words that ended with `,` or `.` or `!`
But if I add a `+` in my regex:

```
String[] words = text.split("[\\s+,.!]+");
for(String w: words) {
    System.out.println(w);
}  
This
is
just
a
text
to
be
used
for
testing
purpose
Nothing
more
```

The empty words are not there. Why is that `+` required so that I avoid the empty words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"[\\s+,.!]"` doesn't do what you think it does. Inside of `[]`s, `+` is treated as a literal character, not the regex special character meaning "one or more".

The empty strings in this first pattern are because substrings like `", "` have an empty string between `","` and `" "`.

`"[\\s+,.!]+"` works because the regex repetition character `+` is in the correct location -- "one or more of any of the characters in the preceding group", i.e. the stuff inside `[]` before the last `+`.

But the `+` inside the group is probably not what you want. That would split `"foo+bar"` into `{"foo", "bar"}`, which appears to be a false positive. Use `"[\\s,.!]+"` to mitigate this.

Comment: So how could I include split on more than one whitespace if I can't use `\\s+` inside the brackets?

Comment: `"[\\s,.!]+"` does that. It treats, for example, `"     "`, `"   .. . . . "`, `"!!,."`, etc as single delimiters. `"foo    ... !!, ,, . ,, bar"` => `{"foo", "bar"}`.